# Change quality profile on SonarQube.com

Tags: java, android, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

I am using the online [SonarQube.com](http://sonarqube.com) free OS services for my Java Android project.

I encountered several bugs where I checked the equality of strings with == instead of .equals().

I found out that sonarqube has what seems to be a good rule to find these bugs: [Objects should be compared with "equals()"](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1698). Unfortunately this rule is disabled in the default [Java Sonarway quality profile](https://sonarqube.com/profiles/show?key=java-sonar-way-45126).

My question is, since I do not have admin privileges on the public [SonarQube.com](http://sonarqube.com) server, is there a way to activate this rule for my project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ability to configure Quality profiles and Quality gates is not implemented yet on sonarqube.com.

SonarSource teams are heavily working on that feature. However no release date can be estimated at the time of writing.

Comment: Quality profiles and Quality gates can now be configured on sonarcloud.io (ex-"sonarqube.com").